# Automatic HTML Form Validation error message is being displayed in an odd location on my browser

Tags: javascript, html

[image: 1]

So this is my problem, the error message on any automatic form validation is being shown in a completely wrong location (this example is on w3schools, but I am also having this problem on my own pages).
I can't find a way to fix that problem

EDIT

So this is how the same page looks in Chrome (left) and Firefox (right).

On the following picture I pressed SUBMIT on Chrome:
[image: 3]

On the following picture I pressed SUBMIT on Firefox:
[image: 2]

Comment: I tried this, but it worked fine! Check again: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_html

Comment: May be for your action file location !, therefore my browser output show error in right place.

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi I just tried again, and I got the same thing, I am using google chrome, so I dont know what could be wrong

Comment: @MdAbdulMomin That had never happened to me before, so I dont know what to do

Comment: @GabrielLealTogni, this is weird, because that error message should find the input position. I never saw this bug before! Try and add inputs inside a div with any class(ex. .form-group)

Comment: Try this  Clear your browser cache & update browser ! Did you checked in Mozilla? @GabrielLealTogni

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/49mxwL5o/2/

Comment: @MdAbdulMomin my browser is on the last version. I cleared the cache and tried again and got the same error. With Firefox it works perfectly, so do you think there's something wrong with my chrome?

Comment: @GabrielLealTogni, no, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/49mxwL5o/4/

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi I'm still getting the same error. This is so weird.

Comment: @GabrielLealTogni Yeah ! Absolutely!

Comment: @GabrielLealTogni, try and add position: relative to the class .form-group, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/49mxwL5o/7/

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi same error. I even uninstalled chome and installed it again, but nothing. Im getting this error over and over

Comment: @GabrielLealTogni, I really would like to help you, but it is very difficult to solve something without testing and seeing exactly that code! I would suggest you to use JQuery Validate Plugin: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi I understand what you are saying. However, I dont think it is a code problem. If it works on Firefox (See edited post), it should be working on chrome. I appreciate very much your help though. I am new to stack overflow and you answered me very quickly. Thank you :)